# Disable annoying sound when handling syskeydown message

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc

Hi I have written my own custom control overriding from MFC CEdit. For that I needed to override the SYS_KEY_UP and SYS_KEY_DOWN. However each time the control handles these message the annoying sound is heard as if the input is invalid or something. Does anyone knwo what generates the sound and how do I disable it.

UPD Code

```
// CShotcutEdit

class CShortcutEdit : public CEdit
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CShortcutEdit)

public:
    CShortcutEdit();
    virtual ~CShortcutEdit();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

    afx_msg UINT OnGetDlgCode();

    afx_msg void OnKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags);

    afx_msg void OnSysKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags);

    afx_msg void OnSysKeyUp(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags);

    afx_msg void OnKeyUp(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags);

    virtual BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg);

    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);

    virtual void PreSubclassWindow();

    virtual void OnChar(UINT uiChar, UINT uiCount, UINT uiFlags);

    // ... Other Members


};

// ShotcutEdit.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GridPlus.h"
#include "ShortcutEdit.h"


// CShotcutEdit

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CShortcutEdit, CEdit)

CShortcutEdit::CShortcutEdit()
{

}

CShortcutEdit::~CShortcutEdit()
{

}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CShortcutEdit, CEdit)
    ON_WM_GETDLGCODE()
    ON_WM_KEYDOWN()
    ON_WM_SYSKEYDOWN()
    ON_WM_SYSKEYUP()
    ON_WM_KEYUP()
    ON_WM_CHAR()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

UINT CShortcutEdit::OnGetDlgCode()
{

    return DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTALLKEYS | DLGC_WANTCHARS;
}

void CShortcutEdit::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CEdit::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BOOL CShortcutEdit::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    return CEdit::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}

void CShortcutEdit::OnSysKeyUp(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
{

}

void CShortcutEdit::OnSysKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
{
    // ... Check for Alt or F10 and translate to string;
}

void CShortcutEdit::OnKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
{
    // .. Check for Ctrl Shift and translate to string

}

void CShortcutEdit::OnKeyUp(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
{
    SetWindowText(L"The desired shortcut is..."); // Should print "alt+f10" for example
}

void CShortcutEdit::OnChar(UINT uiChar, UINT uiCount, UINT uiFlags)
{

}


void CShortcutEdit::PreSubclassWindow()
{
    HideCaret();
    CEdit::PreSubclassWindow();
}

// CShotcutEdit message handlers
```

Comment: Impossible to tell, without seeing the code. I would guess that your derived edit control requests keyboard input, and then changes its mind halfway through and doesn't handle it.

Comment: Done also important that the class implements something similar to  editor for shortcuts on desktop where you can put the key combination to invoke the shortcut. Each time I press say "Alt+a" the shorctut is presented in edit string bit I also hear this annoying sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the default behavior of edit control. Notepad does the same thing in response to Alt+A key.

To avoid the sound, overload `PreTranslateMessage`

```
BOOL CShortcutEdit::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
    {
        UINT nFlags = HIWORD(pMsg->lParam);
        int nChar = (int)pMsg->wParam;

        if (nChar == 'A' && nFlags & KF_ALTDOWN)
        {
            TRACE("ALT+A Key\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return CEdit::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Also, if you don't want an edit control then don't use one, rather than using an edit control and breaking every input.

You probably need [CHotKeyCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa294721%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: It makes sense for Notepad because it cannot handle the Alt-A, however I do handle it and show as desired shortcut in the edit box. Your fix as far as I understand will disable handling the Alt-A at all.

Comment: Wow I indeed missed the control. probably that would solve the problem for me. I do not know if I should mark it as answered as it didn't solve the problem directly.

Comment: That's the overload method, I just put `TRACE` for reference. You can change that and handle it yourself. Does `CHotKeyCtrl` still makes beeps for `Alt` keys? If it does then you can use the same method to stop the beeps. Replace `TRACE` with `hotkey.SetHotKey('A', HOTKEYF_ALT);`